# How do you disable browser autocomplete on web form field / input tags?

Tags: html, forms, browser, autocomplete

How do you disable autocomplete in the major browsers for a specific input (or form field)?

Comment: In some systems where testers have to manually enter a lot of information over and over it might be useful to have the option as configurable so that when testing you can disable it and just hit 'tab > down arrow > tab > down arrow etc...'

Comment: Try https://github.com/terrylinooo/disableautofill.js , it uses JavaScript the skip the auto-fill function from browser.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411944).

Comment: <input name="otp"> is your life saviour in 2022. (Browsers won't provide suggestions for one time passwords.

Comment: thousand answers. Just simply add a hidden email & password field and make them auto complete, this way the browser is happy to fill out something, and it won't affect your user experience.

Comment: Lots of answers get locked on password or username fields and these are all legit issues only that question was not about any specific field.

Answer (score 2889, accepted):

Firefox 30 ignores `autocomplete="off"` for passwords, opting to prompt the user instead whether the password should be stored on the client. Note the following [commentary](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=956906#c100) from May 5, 2014:

> - The password manager *always* prompts if it wants to save a password. Passwords are not saved without permission from the user.
> - We are the third browser to implement this change, after IE and Chrome.

According to the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) documentation, the Boolean form element attribute `autocomplete` prevents form data from being cached in older browsers.

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: This did not work for me in Firefox 3.0.3  I had to put the autocomplete attribute in the FORM rather than the INPUT.

Comment: Autocomplete is only defined in the HTML 5 standards, so it will break any validations you run against HTML 4.*...

Comment: @Winston, you should put it both on the form, AND on the input element itself. That way you cover all the nonstandardness of browsers.

Comment: And remember to disable your [autocomplete = on](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh) extension (if you're using Chrome) before you test your webapp.  Else you'll feel real silly like me. ;)

Comment: Surprised, why this answer is accepted and having so much votes. Even there is nothing special as said others. 
As per my findings most specific and proved solution has provided by @Ben Combee in this thread.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work with me until I put a form with autocomplete='off' around the input field

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: Use `aria-autocomplete="none"`. This seams to work on all browsers including Chromium Edge as of 7/23.

Answer (score 373):

In addition to setting `autocomplete=off`, you could also have your form field names be randomized by the code that generates the page, perhaps by adding some session-specific string to the end of the names.

When the form is submitted, you can strip that part off before processing them on the server-side. This would prevent the web browser from finding context for your field and also might help prevent XSRF attacks because an attacker wouldn't be able to guess the field names for a form submission.

Comment: This is a much better solution compared to using autocomplete="off". All you have to do is generate a new name on every page load and save that name to a $_SESSION for future use: `$_SESSION['codefield_name'] = md5(uniqid('auth', true));`

Comment: No, this is not a better solution, because the origin of preference for this setting is user agent also known as the web browser. There is a difference between supporting certain behaviour (which HTML 5 attempts to do) and forcing it by deciding on behalf of the user, which you suggest is a "much better solution".

Comment: This solution can work with all browsers, so in that respect it is "better". Still, amn is correct, deciding to disable autocomplete on behalf of your users is not a good idea.

This means I would only disable autocomplete in very specific situations, such as when you plan to build your own autocomplete functionality and don't want conflicts or strange behavior.

Comment: Regarding XSRF attacks, I'm not sure what type of attack you were picturing, but couldn't the attacker just strip off the end part the same way you do server-side to identify the fields? Or if the attacker is posting the fields, couldn't they append their own random string since it'll be stripped off by the server?

Comment: @macguru2000 building your own autocomplete is a completely legit and common use-case. Really the browser should make it easier for developers to turn off autocomplete when they need to instead of forcing us to use hacks like this one

Comment: I can't believe this is still an issue.  I get that "the user should have control" however there are use-cases where autocomplete makes no sense.  For example the last thing you want on a data-entry application, i.e. a reception desk, is to have the last record to be pre-populated.  There are many enterprise application use-cases outside the standard e-commerce checkout model that chrome/firefox are catering to

Comment: @amn, it's irrelevant whether you specify autocomplete=off or randomize field name; the browser will not display any previous entries either way, regardless of the "user agent preference".

Answer (score 289):

Most of the major browsers and password managers (correctly, IMHO) now ignore `autocomplete=off`.

Why? Many banks and other "high security" websites added `autocomplete=off` to their login pages "for security purposes" but this actually decreases security since it causes people to change the passwords on these high-security sites to be easy to remember (and thus crack) since autocomplete was broken.

Long ago most password managers started ignoring `autocomplete=off`, and now the browsers are starting to do the same for username/password inputs only.

Unfortunately, bugs in the autocomplete implementations insert username and/or password info into inappropriate form fields, causing form validation errors, or worse yet, accidentally inserting usernames into fields that were intentionally left blank by the user.

What's a web developer to do?

- If you can keep all password fields on a page by themselves, that's a great start as it seems that the presence of a password field is the main trigger for user/pass autocomplete to kick in. Otherwise, read the tips below.
- **Safari** notices that there are 2 password fields and disables autocomplete in this case, assuming it must be a change password form, not a login form. So just be sure to use 2 password fields (new and confirm new) for any forms where you allow
- **Chrome** 34, unfortunately, will try to autofill fields with user/pass whenever it sees a password field. This is quite a bad bug that hopefully, they will change the Safari behavior. However, adding this to the top of your form seems to disable the password autofill:

  ```
  <input type="text" style="display:none">
  <input type="password" style="display:none">
  ```

I haven't yet investigated IE or Firefox thoroughly but will be happy to update the answer if others have info in the comments.

Comment: what do you mean with "adding this on your page seems to disable autofill for the page:"

Comment: @wutzebaer, Chrome notices the hidden password field and halts auto-complete. Reportedly this is to prevent the site stealing password info without the user noticing.

Comment: Your snippet of code prevent autocompletes for login fields on Chrome, Firefox, IE 8 and IE 10.  Did not test IE 11.  Good stuff!  Only simple answer that still works.

Comment: Hello from 2022. I've just tried this solution andd it still works on Firefox 101.0.1 but not on Chrome 102.0.5005.115

Answer (score 208):

The solution for Chrome is to add `autocomplete="new-password"` to the input type password. Please check the example below.

Example:

```
<form name="myForm"" method="post">
   <input name="user" type="text" />
   <input name="pass" type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Chrome always autocomplete the data if it finds a box of *type password*, just enough to indicate for that box `autocomplete = "new-password"`.

> This works well for me.

Note: make sure with <kbd>F12</kbd> that your changes take effect. Many times, browsers save the page in the cache, and this gave me a bad impression that it did not work, but the browser did not actually bring the changes.

Comment: This works in Chrome for other types of fields as well, not just type="password".

Comment: I used it with password, email and text types and it worked. I used it simply like this: autocomplete="new"

Comment: autocomplete="nope" name="pswd" and used <input name="dummyPassword" type="password" style="display:none;"> before the real password input field. This worked for me.

Comment: Examples: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands

Comment: This works in almost all browsers now, not just Chrome: [autocomplete#Browser_compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: This is the best answer as of now.  See the end of this page for more infomation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Comment: `autocomplete="new-password"` and why the "off" parameter doesn't work?? HTML attributes it's really crap. That works on opera browser! Thanks.

Comment: Stopped working in Chrome 94.0 and Edge 94.0

Comment: Seems like one that works for all browsers is "one-time-code" I see it on the page @splashout linked to, but it doesn't work 100% of the time whereas "new-password" seems to work all the time

Answer (score 196):

Sometimes **even autocomplete=off** would **not prevent to fill** in credentials into the wrong fields, but not a user or nickname field.

This workaround is in addition to [apinstein's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags/23234498#23234498) about browser behavior.

#### Fix browser autofill in read-only and set writable on focus (click and tab)

```
 <input type="password" readonly
     onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
     onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);"/>
```

Update:

Mobile Safari sets cursor in the field, but it does not show the virtual keyboard. The new fix works like before, but it handles the virtual keyboard:

```
<input id="email" readonly type="email" onfocus="if (this.hasAttribute('readonly')) {
    this.removeAttribute('readonly');
    // fix for mobile safari to show virtual keyboard
    this.blur();    this.focus();  }" />
```

Live Demo https://jsfiddle.net/danielsuess/n0scguv6/

// UpdateEnd

**Because the browser auto fills credentials to wrong text field!?**

I notice this strange behavior on Chrome and Safari, when there are password fields in *the same form.* I guess the browser looks for a password field to insert your saved credentials. Then it auto fills (just guessing due to observation) the nearest textlike-input field, that appears prior the password field in the DOM. As the browser is the last instance and you can not control it.

This readonly-fix above worked for me.

Comment: An if there is no javascript then the whole form fails. -1

Comment: @JimmyKane the key would be to also add the attribute using javascript in the first place (which dsuess hasn't done here, but just adding for completeness sake).

Comment: @tmelson I understand but still why use js to even disable? Let's avoid js for things that can be improved natively. Again I agree with you though.

Comment: 13 years later, this is still the best option - for those of us using JQuery, here's a quick modification: onfocus="$(this).attr('readonly',false);"

Comment: This is not solution. If JS not works in page, yes it fails. And also, you did a mouse event but many users don't use mouse when they enter inputs.

Answer (score 112):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post"
      autocomplete="off" action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
```

This will work in Internet Explorer and Mozilla Firefox. The downside is that it is not XHTML standard.

Comment: I've noticed that adding it to the form element doesn't always prevent it from being applied to individual inputs within the form. Therefore it is probably best to place it on the input element directly.

Comment: Actually @sholsinger, it's best to put it both on the form, AND on the input element itself. That way you cover all the nonstandardness of browsers.

Comment: Sadly, as of IE 11, Microsoft no longer respects this for `input type="password"`. Hopefully no other browsers choose to remove this functionality.

Comment: Setting `autocomplete="off"` on the `form` is the only thing that worked for Chrome.

Answer (score 63):

As others have said, the answer is `autocomplete="off"`.

However, I think it's worth stating **why** it's a good idea to use this in certain cases as some answers to this and [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471800/how-i-do-to-force-the-browser-to-not-store-the-html-form-field-data) have suggested it's better not to turn it off.

Stopping browsers storing credit card numbers shouldn't be left to users. Too many users won't even realize it's a problem.

It's particularly important to turn it off on fields for credit card security codes. As [this page](http://www.mollerus.net/tom/blog/2007/05/my_best_practices_for_online_credit_card_security.html) states:

> "Never store the security code ... its value depends on the presumption that the only way to supply it is to read it from the physical credit card, proving that the person supplying it actually holds the card."

The problem is, if it's a public computer (cyber cafe, library, etc.), it's then easy for other users to steal your card details, and even on your own machine a malicious website could [steal autocomplete data](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/09/security-basis-and-internet-explorer.html).

Comment: if i went to a site and it remembered my card in the dropdown i'd be very unhappy. id start to wonder how they could be so careless.

Comment: Much simpler / more critical case. When I visit a user's page on the admin portion of my site, it tries to set their username and password to be my admin username and password, not being able to tell that this isn't a login form. I want to have my admin password remembered, but it is a critical error that it tries to apply that remembered username / password to any users that I then edit.

Answer (score 62):

### Always working solution

I've solved the endless fight with Google Chrome with the use of random characters. When you always render autocomplete with random string, it will never remember anything.

```
<input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="rutjfkde">
```

Hope that it will help to other people.

**Update 2022:**

Chrome made this improvement: `autocomplete="new-password"` which will solve it but I am not sure, if Chrome change it again to different functionality after some time.

Comment: This works even better. You can add a small JS that generates a random code for every page load, and add that code to the input field:
<code>
 function autoId(){
    var autoId = "";
    var dict = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for(var i=0; i<12; i++){
        autoId += dict.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * dict.length));
    }
    return autoId;
}
$('.autocompleteoff').attr('autocomplete', autoId());</code>
You can add the `autocompleteoff` class to your desired input field.

Comment: not working in my chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Chrome has been fixed to use the standardized "off" now

Comment: Sadly it works better than what is called standard on chrome

Comment: You have to generate new random string on each reload page.

Comment: Today I found that Chrome will overwrite random string with "Off". I can not believe that Chrome developers doing this attribute bad and noncontrol. Why ohh my got.

Comment: You can also use Math.random().toString() atleast it worked for me in material UI

Comment: The "Update 2022" with the `autocomplete="new-password"` works, thanks!

Comment: autocomplete="off" works for firefox in 2022

Answer (score 37):

I'd have to beg to differ with those answers that say to avoid disabling auto-complete.

The first thing to bring up is that auto-complete not being explicitly disabled on login form fields is a PCI-DSS fail. In addition, if a users' local machine is compromised then any autocomplete data can be trivially obtained by an attacker due to it being stored in the clear.

There is certainly an argument for usability, however there's a very fine balance when it comes to which form fields should have autocomplete disabled and which should not.

Comment: It has just come to my attention that IE doesn't trigger onChange events when you fill a text input using AutoComplete. We've got dozens of forms and over a thousand onChange events (input validations, business logic) scattered all over them. Recently we upgraded IE to a newer version and all of a sudden weird things started to happen. Luckily we're running an intranet app and autocomplete is not an UX issue for us, it's easier to just turn it off.

Comment: If a users local machine is compromised, they are screwed, period. It could have a keylogger installed, it could have a fake SSL root certificate added and everything sent through a false proxy etc.

I have a real reason to disable autocomplete - When I log in as an admin and visit the edit user page, it assigns that user my admin username and password. I need to prevent this behaviour.

Comment: Browser vendors seem to be looking out for their own interests.  Saved passwords = user lock-in.  And autocomplete on/off was too simple - why not a complex standard of semantic hints ( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofill-field-name ) which, by-the-way, allows the browser to collect valuable semantic data from the sites each user visits ?

Comment: the specific use case I am trying to solve is this: they are already logged in. but now they are about to access something even more sensitive. I want to show a dialog that makes them re-authenticate, against the possibility that they walked off to have a smoke and a bad person sat down in their chair. have tried several techniques to defeat autocompletion, and nothing works. now I am thinking, maybe, at least, use good old  'password = window.prompt("Please re-enter your password")' plus the username in the session, and try to authenticating that.

Answer (score 36):

Three options:

First:

```
<input type='text' autocomplete='off' />
```

Second:

```
<form action='' autocomplete='off'>
```

Third (JavaScript code):

```
$('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Comment: The first and second options should be one option, since it varies on how browsers handle this.

Comment: Tried $formElement.attr('autocomplete', 'off'); and it does not work.

Answer (score 31):

> In addition to

```
autocomplete="off"
```

> Use

```
readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
```

for the inputs that you do not want them to remember form data (`username`, `password`, etc.) as shown below:

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" autocomplete="off" readonly 
    onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >

<input type="password" name="Password" autocomplete="off" readonly 
    onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >
```

Comment: For me in IE11 I can't type into the text box even after the onfocus removes the readonly attribute. However, if I click a second time on the text box then I can type.

Comment: I ran into the same issue with IE11 (can't type until second focus). Adding a blur and then focus again works.

```$(document).on('focus', 'input:password[readonly="readonly"]', function () {
            $(this).prop('readonly', false).blur().focus();
        });```

Comment: @Andrew Sure, you can. This is the core principle to overwhelm this issue and I also added an update containing full code example ;)

Comment: I've also added `onfocusout="this.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');"`

Answer (score 27):

This works for me.

```
<input name="pass" type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

We can also use this strategy in other controls like text, select etc

Answer (score 26):

On a related or actually, on the completely opposite note -

> "If you're the user of the aforementioned form and want to re-enable
>   the autocomplete functionality, use the 'remember password'
>   bookmarklet from this [bookmarklets
>   page](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/forms.html). It removes
>   all `autocomplete="off"` attributes from all forms on the page. Keep
>   fighting the good fight!"

Answer (score 25):

Just set `autocomplete="off"`. There is a very good reason for doing this: You want to provide your own autocomplete functionality!

Answer (score 23):

None of the solutions worked for me in this conversation.

I finally figured out a **pure HTML solution** that doesn't require **any JavaScript**, works in modern browsers (except Internet Explorer; there had to at least be one catch, right?), and does not require you to disable autocomplete for the entire form.

Simply turn off autocomplete on the `form` and then turn it ON for any `input` you wish it to work within the form. For example:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
    <!-- These inputs will not allow autocomplete and Chrome
         won't highlight them yellow! -->
    <input name="username"  />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
    <!-- This field will allow autocomplete to work even
         though we've disabled it on the form -->
    <input name="another_field" autocomplete="on" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 22):

We did actually use *sasb*'s idea for one site.

It was a medical software web app to run a doctor's office. However, many of our clients were surgeons who used lots of different workstations, including semi-public terminals. So, they wanted to make sure that a doctor who doesn't understand the implication of auto-saved passwords or isn't paying attention can't accidentally leave their login information easily accessible.

Of course, this was before the idea of private browsing that is starting to be featured in Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 3.1, etc. Even so, many physicians are forced to use old school browsers in hospitals with IT that won't change.

So, we had the login page generate random field names that would only work for that post. Yes, it's less convenient, but it's just hitting the user over the head about not storing login information on public terminals.

Comment: There isn't any current user by the name "sasb" here (incl. in deleted answer). (Though comments on *some* deleted answers are no longer visible.) What answer (or comment) does it refer to?

Answer (score 22):

I've been trying endless solutions, and then I found this:

Instead of `autocomplete="off"` just simply use `autocomplete="false"`

As simple as that, and it works like a charm in Google Chrome as well!

Comment: As you said in chrome, the off value doesn't work. It needs to be "false"

Comment: Works for me on Chrome 44.0.2403.130.

Comment: Tried this: $formElement.attr('autocomplete', 'false'); sorry does not work.

Answer (score 20):

I think `autocomplete=off` is supported in HTML 5.

Ask yourself why you want to do this though - it may make sense in some situations but don't do it just for the sake of doing it.

It's less convenient for users and not even a security issue in OS X (mentioned by Soren below). If you're worried about people having their passwords stolen remotely - a keystroke logger could still do it even though your app uses `autcomplete=off`.

As a user who chooses to have a browser remember (most of) my information, I'd find it annoying if your site didn't remember mine.

Answer (score 19):

Adding `autocomplete="off"` is not going to cut it.

Change the `input` type attribute to `type="search"`.
Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Comment: It is a hack. The field is not a search field. In the future this could cause troubles.

Comment: Many password managers (like 1Password) also "respect" this hack by the way

Answer (score 19):

The best solution:

Prevent autocomplete username (or email) and password:

```html
<input type="email" name="email"><!-- Can be type="text" -->
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

Prevent autocomplete a field:

```html
<input type="text" name="field" autocomplete="nope">
```

Explanation:
`autocomplete` continues work in `<input>`, `autocomplete="off"` does not work, but you can change `off` to a random string, like `nope`.

Works in:

- Chrome: 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63 and 64
- Firefox: 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57 and 58

Comment: I found this to work in my preliminary testing.  So odd that "off" doesn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for Chrome on Android. I've tried setting string values for the `autocomplete` attribute and it still displays previous entries as autocomplete suggestions under the input.

Comment: @tebs1200 Which one? The password field or the text field?

Comment: @Cava sorry for the delayed response. The text field. It doesn't matter what value I set `autocomplete` to, i still get a suggestion dropdown based on previously entered values. It's fine on desktop, but not on Android chrome.

Answer (score 17):

Use a non-standard name and id for the fields, so rather than "name" have "name_". Browsers will then not see it as being the name field.

The best part about it is that you can do this to some, but not all, fields and it will autocomplete some, but not all fields.

Comment: The problem with this is if any other sites use "name_" to achieve the same objective then you're back to square one.

Comment: so make it "mysite_name". If anyone else is using that, I'd ask them questions...

Comment: this messes up some of those automatic populating utilities

Answer (score 16):

I just ran into this problem and tried several failures, but this one works for me (found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)):

> In some cases, the browser will keep suggesting autocompletion values
> even if the autocomplete attribute is set to off. This unexpected
> behavior can be quite puzzling for developers. The trick to really
> force the no-completion is to assign a random string to the attribute
> like so:

```
autocomplete="nope"
```

Comment: Where on MDN, that link you added doesn't mention anything with "nope". Maybe the page has changed?

Answer (score 13):

In order to avoid the invalid XHTML, you can set this attribute using JavaScript. An example using jQuery:

```
<input type="text" class="noAutoComplete" ... />

$(function() {
    $('.noAutoComplete').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
});
```

The problem is that users without JavaScript will get the autocomplete functionality.

Comment: this doesn't avoid invalid xhtml, it simply adds the invalid bit dynamically after you have checked it it declared it to be valid!

Comment: @Andiih: So is there a way to make autocomplete work in xhtml?

Comment: Work (or stop it working which is the goal): yes as above. But valid - no.

Answer (score 13):

Adding the

`autocomplete="off"`

to the form tag will disable the browser autocomplete (what was previously typed into that field) from all `input` fields within that particular form.

Tested on:

- Firefox 3.5, 4 BETA
- Internet Explorer 8
- Chrome

Answer (score 13):

I can't believe this is still an issue so long after it's been reported. The previous solutions didn't work for me, as [Safari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) seemed to know when the element was not displayed or off-screen, however the following did work for me:

```
<div style="height:0px; overflow:hidden; ">
  Username <input type="text" name="fake_safari_username" >
  Password <input type="password" name="fake_safari_password">
</div>
```

Comment: so, putting this prior to the actual username and password fields worked? the browser filled those and not the real ones

Answer (score 13):

So here is it:

```js
function turnOnPasswordStyle() {
  $('#inputpassword').attr('type', "password");
}
```

```html
<input oninput="turnOnPasswordStyle()" id="inputpassword" type="text">
```

Comment: Looks like good idea if style text boxes to prevent flash of visible password.

Comment: Thanks so much, this did the job +1, my variation to your solution was to make it by single line: <input oninput="this.type='password'" id="inputpassword" type="text">

Comment: @HasnaaIbraheem Thanks (: sometimes more readable is better .

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work - readonly attr worked but messed up the tab order.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was it tested on (incl. versions)?

Answer (score 12):

Try these too if just `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work:

```
autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"
```

Comment: autoComplete for React... $0.02

Answer (score 12):

This is a security issue that browsers ignore now. Browsers identify and store content using input names, even if developers consider the information to be sensitive and should not be stored.

Making an input name different between 2 requests will solve the problem (but will still be saved in browser's cache and will also increase browser's cache).

Asking the user to activate or deactivate options in their browser's settings is not a good solution. The issue can be fixed in the backend.

Here's the fix. All autocomplete elements are generated with a hidden input like this:

```
<?php $r = md5(rand() . microtime(TRUE)); ?>
<form method="POST" action="./">
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo $r; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="__autocomplete_fix_<?php echo $r; ?>" value="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The server then processes the post variables like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kBJtN))

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $newKey = preg_replace('~^__autocomplete_fix_~', '', $key, 1, $count);
    if ($count) {
        $_POST[$val] = $_POST[$newKey];
        unset($_POST[$key], $_POST[$newKey]);
    }
}
```

The value can be accessed as usual

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```

And the browser won't be able to suggest information from the previous request or from previous users.

This will continue to work even if browsers update their techniques to ignore/respect autocomplete attributes.

Answer (score 10):

None of the hacks mentioned here worked for me in Chrome.
There's a discussion of the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c41

Adding this inside a `<form>` works (at least for now):

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="PreventChromeAutocomplete" name="PreventChromeAutocomplete" autocomplete="address-level4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Note that using this technique, FireFox will still actually autofill that hidden field, which will be included when submitting the form. That would likely be bad, as the password would then be transfered over a potentially unsecured connection. Fortunately adding `maxlength="0"` does prevent firefox from autofilling the field.

Answer (score 10):

Things had changed now as I tried it myself old answers no longer work.

Implementation that I'm sure it will work. I test this in Chrome, Edge and Firefox and it does do the trick. You may also try this and tell us your experience.

```
set the autocomplete attribute of the password input element to "new-password"

<form autocomplete="off">
....other element
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password"/>
</form>
```

This is according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password)

If you are defining a user management page where a user can specify a new password for another person, and therefore you want to prevent autofilling of password fields, you can use `autocomplete="new-password"`

This is a hint, which browsers are not required to comply with. However modern browsers have stopped autofilling `<input>`  elements with autocomplete="new-password" for this very reason.

Comment: only this solution is working from entire internet

Answer (score 9):

You may use it in `input`.

For example;

```
<input type=text name="test" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Many modern browsers do not support autocomplete="off" for login fields anymore.
`autocomplete="new-password"` is wokring instead, more information [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Comment: not any more, stopped working in recent browsers

Answer (score 8):

Here's the perfect solution that will work in all browsers as of May 2021!

## TL;DR

Rename your input field names and field ids to something non-related like `'data_input_field_1'`. Then add the `&#8204;` character into the middle of your labels. This is a non-printing character, so you won't see it, but it tricks the browser into not recognizing the field as one needing auto-completing, thus no built-in auto-complete widget is shown!

## The Details

Almost all browsers use a combination of the field's name, id, placeholder, and label to determine if the field belongs to a group of address fields that could benefit from auto-completion. So if you have a field like `<input type="text" id="address" name="street_address">` pretty much all browsers will interpret the field as being an address field. As such the browser will display its built-in auto-completion widget. The dream would be that using the attribute `autocomplete="off"` would work, unfortunately, most browsers nowadays don't obey the request.

So we need to use some trickery to get the browsers to not display the built-in autocomplete widget. The way we will do that is by fooling the browser into believing that the field is not an address field at all.

Start by renaming the **id** and the **name** attributes to something that won't give away that you're dealing with address-related data. So rather than using `<input type="text" id="city-input" name="city">`, use something like this instead `<input type="text" id="input-field-3" name="data_input_field_3">`. The browser doesn't know what data_input_field_3 represents. But you do.

If possible, don't use **placeholder text** as most browsers will also take that into account. If you have to use placeholder text, then you'll have to get creative and make sure you're not using any words relating to the address parameter itself (like `City`). Using something like `Enter location` can do the trick.

The final parameter is the **label** attached to the field. However, if you're like me, you probably want to keep the label intact and display recognizable fields to your users like "Address", "City", "State", "Country". Well, great news: ***you can***! The best way to achieve that is to insert a *Zero-Width Non-Joiner Character*, `&#8204;`, as the second character in the label. So replacing `<label>City</label>` with `<label>C&#8204;ity</label>`. This is a non-printing character, so your users will see `City`, but the browser will be tricked into seeing `C ity` and not recognize the field!

Mission accomplished! If all went well, the browser should not display the built-in address auto-completion widget on those fields anymore!

Comment: Re *"add the `&#8204;` character into the middle of your labels"*: How is that going to be maintainable? How is a new developer to discover that in a timely manner? How do you suggest documenting the invisible characters (also if they aren't invisible in some contexts)?

Answer (score 6):

Chrome is [planning to support this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c123).

For now the best suggestion is to use an input type that is rarely autocompleted.

[Chrome discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c33)

```
<input type='search' name="whatever" />
```

To be compatible with Firefox, use normal autocomplete='off'

```
<input type='search' name="whatever" autocomplete='off' />
```

Answer (score 6):

You can disable autocomplete if you remove the `form` tag.

The same was done by my bank and I was wondering how they did this. It even removes the value that was already remembered by the browser after you remove the tag.

Answer (score 6):

**No fake inputs, no javascript!**

There is no way to disable autofill consistently across browsers. I have tried all the different suggestions and none of them work in all browsers. The only way is not using password input at all. Here's what I came up with:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'PasswordDots';
        src: url('text-security-disc.woff') format('woff');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }

    input.password {
        font-family: 'PasswordDots' !important;
        font-size: 8px !important;
    }
</style>

<input class="password" type="text" spellcheck="false" />
```

Download: [text-security-disc.woff](https://github.com/noppa/text-security/blob/master/dist/text-security-disc.woff)

Here's how my final result looks like:

[image: Password Mask]

The negative side effect is that it's possible to copy plain text from the input, though it should be possible to prevent that with some JS.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" aria-haspopup="false" spellcheck="false" />
```

i find it works for me on all browsers. When I make use of only the autocomplete it doesn't work except i combine all the attributes that you see. Also i got the solution from google form input field

Comment: An explanation would be good, especially on old questions with a lot of answers already. Do you need *all* those attributes set?

Comment: Ok. Please [edit] such details into your answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        try {
            $("input[type='text']").each(
                function(){
                   $(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");
                });
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How is this any different than setting it to autocomplete=off in html, which doesn't work these days?

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was it tested on (including version information) and under what conditions?

Answer (score 5):

This is what we called autocomplete of a textbox.

[image]

We can disable autocomplete of a Textbox in two ways:

1. By Browser Label
2. By Code

   To disable in a browser, go to the setting

[image: To disable in the browser, go to the setting]

[image: Go to Advanced Settings and uncheck the checkbox and then Restore.]

Go to *Advanced Settings* and uncheck the checkbox and then Restore.

If you want to disable in coding label you can do as follows -

Using `AutoCompleteType="Disabled"`:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_userid" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox>
```

By Setting Form `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_userid" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
```

By Setting Form `autocomplete="off"`:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="off">
    // Your content
</form>
```

By using code in the .cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        txt_userid.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
    }
}
```

**By using jQuery**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txt_userid').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If your issue is having a password field being auto-completed, then you may find this useful...

We had this issue in several areas of our site where the business wanted to re-query the user for their username and password and specifically did not want the password autofill to work for contractual reasons.  We found that the easiest way to do this is to put in a fake password field for the browser to find and fill while the real password field remains untouched.

```
<!-- This is a fake password input to defeat the browser's autofill behavior -->
<input type="password" id="txtPassword" style="display:none;" />
<!-- This is the real password input -->
<input type="password" id="txtThisIsTheRealPassword" />
```

Note that in Firefox and IE, it was simply enough to put any input of type password before the actual one but Chrome saw through that and forced me to actually name the fake password input (by giving it an obvious password id) to get it to "bite".  I used a class to implement the style instead of using an embedded style so try that if the above doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

[The answer **dsuess** posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags/24247840#24247840) with the readonly was very clever and worked.

But as I am using [Bootstrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_%28front-end_framework%29), the readonly input field was - until focused - marked with grey background. While the document loads, you can trick the browser by simply locking and unlocking the input.

So I had an idea to implement this into a jQuery solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").attr('readonly', true);
    $("input").removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

My problem was mostly autofill with Chrome, but I think this is probably more problematic than autocomplete.

Trick: using a timer to reset the form and set the password fields to blank. The 100 ms duration seems to be the minimum for it to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $form = $('#formId');
        $form[0].reset();
        $form.find('INPUT[type=password]').val('');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Doesnt help with default values, but it is an idea, as you could track & replace the values with the ones that were there originally I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

I use this `TextMode="password" autocomplete="new-password"` and in in page load in aspx `txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", '');`

Answer (score 5):

Google Chrome ignores the `autocomplete="off"` attribute for certain inputs, including password inputs and common inputs detected by name.

For example, if you have an input with name `address`, then Chrome will provide autofill suggestions from addresses entered on other sites, *even if you tell it not to*:

```
<input type="string" name="address" autocomplete="off">
```

If you don't want Chrome to do that, then you can rename or namespace the form field's name:

```
<input type="string" name="mysite_addr" autocomplete="off">
```

If you don't mind autocompleting values which were previously entered on your site, then you can leave autocomplete enabled.  Namespacing the field name should be enough to prevent values remembered from other sites from appearing.

```
<input type="string" name="mysite_addr" autocomplete="on">
```

Answer (score 4):

It could be important to know that Firefox (I think only Firefox) uses a value called `ismxfilled` that basically forces autocomplete.

`ismxfilled="0"` for `OFF`

or

`ismxfilled="1"` for `ON`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't seem to be possible to achieve this without using a combination client side and server side code.

In order to make sure that the user must fill in the form every time without autocomplete I use the following techniques:

1. Generate the form field names on the server and use hidden input fields to store those names, so that when submitted to the server the server side code can use the generated names to access the field values. This is to stop the user from having the option to auto populate the fields.
2. Place three instances of each form field on the form and hide the first and last fields of each set using css and then disable them after page load using javascript. This is to prevent the browser from filling in the fields automatically.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the javascript, css and html as described in #2 https://jsfiddle.net/xnbxbpv4/

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".disable-input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

css:

```css
.disable-input {
  display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="username" placeholder="username" class="disable-input">
<input type="email" name="username" placeholder="username">
<input type="email" name="username" placeholder="username" class="disable-input">
<br>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="disable-input">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" class="disable-input">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Here is a rough example of what the server code using asp.net with razor would be to facilitate #1

model:

```
public class FormModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

controller:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Form()
    {
        var m = new FormModel();

        m.Username = "F" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        m.Password = "F" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        return View(m);
    }

    public ActionResult Form(FormModel m)
    {
        var u = Request.Form[m.Username];
        var p = Request.Form[m.Password];

        // todo: do something with the form values

        ...

        return View(m);
    }
}
```

view:

```
@model FormModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Form"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Password)

    <input type="email" name="@Model.Username" placeholder="username" class="disable-input">
    <input type="email" name="@Model.Username" placeholder="username">
    <input type="email" name="@Model.Username" placeholder="username" class="disable-input">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="@Model.Password" placeholder="password" class="disable-input">
    <input type="password" name="@Model.Password" placeholder="password">
    <input type="password" name="@Model.Password" placeholder="password" class="disable-input">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Easy Hack

Make input read-only

```
<input type="text" name="name" readonly="readonly">
```

Remove read-only after timeout

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('input[name="name"]').prop('readonly', false);
    }, 50);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried almost all the answers, but the new version of Chrome is smart; if you write

```
autocomplete="randomstring" or autocomplete="rutjfkde"
```

it automatically converts it to

```
autocomplete="off"
```

when the input control receives the focus.

So, I did it using jQuery, and my solution is as follows.

```
$("input[type=text], input[type=number], input[type=email], input[type=password]").focus(function (e) {
    $(this).attr("autocomplete", "new-password");
})
```

This is the easiest and will do the trick for any number of controls you have on the form.

Answer (score 4):

There are many answers but most of them are hacks or some kind of workaround.

There are three cases here.

**Case I:** If this is your standard login form. Turning it off by any means is probably bad. Think hard if you really need to do it. Users are accustomed to browsers remembering and storing the passwords. You shouldn't change that standard behaviour in most cases.

In case you still want to do it, see **Case III**

**Case II:** When this is not your regular login form but `name` or `id` attribute of inputs is not "like" email, login, username, user_name, password.

Use

```
<input type="text" name="yoda" autocomplete="off">
```

**Case III:** When this is not your regular login form but `name` or `id` attribute of inputs is "like" email, login, username, user_name, password.

For example:
login, abc_login, password, some_password, password_field.

All browsers come with password management features offering to remember them OR suggesting stronger passwords. That's how they do it.

However, suppose you are an admin of a site and can create users and set their passwords. In this case you wouldn't want browsers to offer these features.

In such cases, `autocomplete="off"` will not work. Use `autocomplete="new-password"`

```
<input type="text" name="yoda" autocomplete="new-password">
```

**Helpful Link:**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion

Answer (score 4):

To disable the autocomplete of text in forms, use the autocomplete attribute of  and  elements. You'll need the "off" value of this attribute.

This can be done in a  for a complete form or for specific  elements:

1. Add autocomplete="off" onto the  element to disable autocomplete for the entire form.
2. Add autocomplete="off" for a specific  element of the form.

**form**

```
<form action="#" method="GET" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

**input**

```
<input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off">
```

Answer (score 3):

Safari does not change its mind about autocomplete if you set `autocomplete="off"` dynamically from JavaScript. However, it would respect if you do that on per-field basis.

```
$(':input', $formElement).attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to create an invisible field with the same name before the original one. That will make the browser auto populate the hidden field.

I use the following jQuery snippet:

```
// Prevent input autocomplete
$.fn.preventAutocomplete = function() {
    this.each(function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el
            .clone(false, false) // Make a copy (except events)
            .insertBefore($el)   // Place it before original field
            .prop('id', '')      // Prevent ID duplicates
            .hide()              // Make it invisible for user
        ;
    });
};
```

And then just `$('#login-form input').preventAutocomplete();`

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, I have used some CSS tricks and the following works for me.

```css
input {
    text-security:disc;
    -webkit-text-security:disc;
    -mox-text-security:disc;
}
```

Please read [this](https://medium.com/@idanhareven/how-to-workaround-browsers-save-password-password-autocomplete-features-135b91ad06d2) article for further detail.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent browser auto fill with the user's saved site login credentials, place a text and password input field at the top of the form with non empty values and style "position: absolute; top: -999px; left:-999px" set to hide the fields.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username_X" value="-" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left:-999px" />
  <input type="password" name="password_X" value="-" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left:-999px" />
  <!-- Place the form elements below here. -->
</form>
```

It is important that a text field precede the password field.  Otherwise the auto fill may not be prevented in some cases.

It is important that the value of both the text and password fields not be empty, to prevent default values from being overwritten in some cases.

It is important that these two fields are before the "real" password type field(s) in the form.

For newer browsers that are html 5.3 compliant the autocomplete attribute value "new-password" should work.

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="new-password" />
</form>
```

A combination of the two methods can be used to support both older and newer browsers.

```
<form>
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="text" readonly tabindex="-1" />
    <input type="password" readonly tabindex="-1" />
  </div>
  <!-- Place the form elements below here. -->
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" />
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" autocomplete="new-password" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent the common browser plug-in `LastPass` from auto-filling a field as well, you can add the attribute `data-lpignore="true"` added to the other suggestions on this thread. Note that this doesn't only apply to password fields.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="false" data-lpignore="true" />
```

I was trying to do this same thing a while back, and was stumped because none of the suggestions I found worked for me. Turned out it was `LastPass`.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers didn't help as the browser was simply ignoring them. (Some of them were not cross-browser compatible). The fix that worked for me is:

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="new-password" />
    <input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
</form>
```

I set autofill="off" on the form tag and autofill="new-password" wherever the autofill was not necessary.

Comment: Re *"Most of the answers didn't help as the browser was simply ignoring them"*: Can you be more specific? What browser(s) and what version(s) and on what platform(s) (incl. version(s)). Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57001445/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

As of Dec 2019:

Before answering this question let me say, I tried almost all the answers here on SO and from different forums but couldn't find a solution that works for all modern browsers and IE11.

So here is the solution I found, and I believe it's not yet discussed or mentioned in this post.

According to Mozilla Dev Network(MDN) post about [how to turn off form autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

> By default, browsers remember information that the user submits through  fields on websites. This enables the browser to offer autocompletion (that is, suggest possible completions for fields that the user has started typing in) or autofill (that is, pre-populate certain fields upon load)

On same article they discussed the usage of `autocmplete` property and its limitation. As we know, not all browsers honor this attribute as we desire.

**Solution**

So at the end of the article they shared a solution that works for all browsers including IE11+Edge. It is basically a jQuery plugin that do the trick.
Here is the [link](https://terrylinooo.github.io/jquery.disableAutoFill/) to jQuery plugin and how it works.

Code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('#frmLogin').disableAutoFill({
        passwordField: '.password'
    });
});
```

Point to notice in HTML is that password field is of type text and `password` class is applied to identify that field:

```
<input id="Password" name="Password" type="text" class="form-control password">
```

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

1- Add `autocomplete="off"` onto `<form>` element.

2- Add hidden `<input>` with `autocomplete="false"` as a first children element of the form with `display: none`.

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="">
    <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is not to insert the password field into the DOM before the user wants to change the password. This may be applicable in certain cases:

In our system we have a password field which in an admin page, so we must avoid inadvertently setting other users' passwords. The form has an extra checkbox that will toggle the password field visibility for this reason.

So in this case, autofill from a password manager becomes a double problem, because the input won't even be visible to the user.

The solution was to have the checkbox trigger whether the password field is inserted in the DOM, not just its visibility.

Pseudo implementation for AngularJS:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="createPassword">
<input ng-if="changePassword" type="password">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use autocomplete = off in input controls to avoid auto completion

For example:

```
<input type=text name="test" autocomplete="off" />
```

if the above code doesn't works then try to add those attributes also

```
autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"
```

or

Change input type attribute to `type="search"`. Google doesn't apply auto-fill to inputs with a type of search.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is Change the text inputs type dynamically using angular js directive
and it works like charm

first add 2 hidden text fields

and just add a angular directive like this

```
 (function () {

    'use strict';

    appname.directive('changePasswordType', directive);

    directive.$inject = ['$timeout', '$rootScope',  '$cookies'];

    function directive($timeout,  $rootScope, $cookies) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope,element) {
            var process = function () {
                var elem =element[0];
                elem.value.length > 0 ? element[0].setAttribute("type", "password") :
                element[0].setAttribute("type", "text");
            }

            element.bind('input', function () {
                process();
            });

            element.bind('keyup', function () {
                process();
            });
        }
    }
})()
```

then use it in your text field where you need to prevent auto complete

```
    <input type="text" style="display:none">\\can avoid this 2 lines
    <input type="password" style="display:none">
    <input type="text"  autocomplete="new-password" change-password-type>
```

NB: dont forget to include jquery, and set `type ="text"` initially

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something that took the field management completely out of the browser's hands, so to speak. In this example, there's a single standard text input field to capture a password — no email, user name, etc...

```html
<input id='input_password' type='text' autocomplete='off' autofocus>
```

There's a variable named "input", set to be an empty string...

```javascript
var input = "";
```

The field events are monitored by jQuery...

1. On focus, the field content and the associated "input" variable are always cleared.
2. On keypress, any alphanumeric character, as well as some defined symbols, are appended to the "input" variable, and the field input is replaced with a bullet character. Additionally, when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed, and the typed characters (stored in the "input" variable) are sent to the server via Ajax. (See "Server Details" below.)
3. On keyup, the <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>Arrow</kbd> keys cause the "input" variable and field values to be flushed. (I could have gotten fancy with arrow navigation and the focus event, and used *.selectionStart* to figure out where the user had clicked or was navigating, but it's not worth the effort for a password field.) Additionally, pressing the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key truncates both the variable and field content accordingly.

---

```javascript
$("#input_password").off().on("focus", function(event) {
    $(this).val("");
    input = "";

}).on("keypress", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.key !== "Enter" && event.key.match(/^[0-9a-z!@#\$%&*-_]/)) {
        $(this).val( $(this).val() + "•" );
        input += event.key;
    }
    else if (event.key == "Enter") {
        var params = {};
        params.password = input;

        $.post(SERVER_URL, params, function(data, status, ajax) {
            location.reload();
        });
    }

}).on("keyup", function(event) {
    var navigationKeys = ["Home", "End", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown"];
    if ($.inArray(event.key, navigationKeys) > -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).val("");
        input = "";
    }
    else if (event.key == "Backspace") {
        var length = $(this).val().length - 1 > 0 ? $(this).val().length : 0;
        input = input.substring(0, length);
    }
});
```

---

**Front-End Summary**

In essence, this gives the browser nothing useful to capture. Even if it overrides the autocomplete setting, and/or presents a dropdown with previously entered values, all it has is bullets stored for the field value.

---

**Server Details** (optional reading)

As shown above, JavaScript executes *location.reload()* as soon as the server returns a JSON response. (This logon technique is for access to a restricted administration tool. Some of the overkill, related to the cookie content, could be skipped for a more generalized implementation.) Here are the details:

- When a user navigates to the site, the server looks for a legitimate cookie.
- If there isn't any cookie, the logon page is presented. When the user
  enters a password and it is sent via Ajax, the server confirms the password and also checks
  to see if the user's IP address is in an Authorized IP address list.
- If either the password or IP address are not recognized, the server doesn't generate a cookie, so when the page reloads, the user sees the same logon page.
- If both the password and IP address are recognized, the server generates a
  cookie that has a ten-minute life span, and it also stores two scrambled values that correspond with the time-frame and IP address.
- When the page reloads, the server finds the cookie and verifies that
  the scrambled values are correct (i.e., that the time-frame corresponds with the cookie's date and that the IP address is the same).
- The process of authenticating and updating the cookie is repeated every time the user interacts with the server, whether they are logging in, displaying data, or updating a record.
- If at all times the cookie's values are correct, the server presents the full website (if the user is logging in) or fulfills whatever display or update request was submitted.
- If at any time the cookie's values are not correct, the server removes the current cookie which then, upon reload, causes the logon page to be
  redisplayed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this option was removed in most browsers, so it is not possible to disable the password hint.

Until today, I did not find a good solution to work around this problem. What we have left now is to hope that one day this option will come back.

Answer (score 2):

I went through the same problem, today 09/10/2019 only solution I found was this

Add autocomplete="off" into the form tag.

put 1 false inputs after opening form tag.

```
<input id="username" style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered">
```

but it won't work on password type field, try

```
<input type="text" oninput="turnOnPasswordStyle()" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" id="password" required>
```

on script

```
function turnOnPasswordStyle() {
    $('#password').attr('type', "password");
}
```

This is tested on Chrome-78, IE-44, Firefox-69

Answer (score 2):

The autofill functionality changes the value without selecting the field. We could use that in our state management to ignore state changes before the select event.

An example in [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class NoAutoFillInput extends Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            locked: true
        }
    }

    onChange(event){
        if (!this.state.locked){
            this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
        }
    }

    render() {
        let props = {...this.props, ...{onChange: this.onChange.bind(this)}, ...{onSelect: () => this.setState({locked: false})}};
        return <input {...props}/>;
    }
}

export default NoAutoFillInput;
```

If the browser tries to fill the field, the element is still locked and the state is not affected. Now you can just replace the input field with a NoAutoFillInput component to prevent autofill:

```
<div className="form-group row">
    <div className="col-sm-2">
        <NoAutoFillInput type="text" name="myUserName" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" value={this.state.userName} onChange={value => this.setState({userName: value})}/>
    </div>
    <div className="col-sm-2">
        <NoAutoFillInput type="password" name="myPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={value => this.setState({password: value})}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, this idea could be used with other JavaScript frameworks as well.

Answer (score 2):

None of the solutions I've found at this day bring a real working response.

Solutions with an `autocomplete` attribute do not work.

So, this is what I wrote for myself:

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" onkeyup="if (this.value.length > 0) this.setAttribute('type', 'password'); else this.setAttribute('type', 'text');" >
```

You should do this for every input field you want as a password type on your page.

And this works.

cheers

Answer (score 2):

**Pretty sure this is the most generic solution as of today**

This stops auto-complete and the popup suggestion box too.

**Intro**

Let's face it, autocomplete=off or new-password doesn't seem to work.
It's should do but it doesn't and every week we discover something else has changed and the browser is filling a form out with more random garbage we don't want.  I've discovered a really simple solution that doesn't need autocomplete on sign in pages.

**How to implement**

Step 1). Add the same function call to the onmousedown and onkeyup attributes for your username and password fields, making sure you give them an id AND note the code at the end of the function call. md=mousedown and ku=keyup

For the username field only add a value of `&nbsp;` as this prevents the form auto-filling on entry to the page.

For example:

```html
<input type="text" value="&nbsp;" id="myusername" onmousedown="protectMe(this,'md')" onkeyup="protectMe(this,'ku')" />
```

Step 2). Include this function on the page

```js
function protectMe(el,action){

 // Remove the white space we injected on startup
 var v = el.value.trim();
 
// Ignore this reset process if we are typing content in
// and only acknowledge a keypress when it's the last Delete
// we do resulting in the form value being empty
 if(action=='ku' && v != ''){return;} 

// Fix double quote issue (in the form input) that results from writing the outerHTML back to itself
  v = v.replace(/"/g,'\\"'); 
  
  // Reset the popup appearing when the form came into focus from a click  by rewriting it back
  el.outerHTML=el.outerHTML; 

  // Issue instruction to refocus it again, insert the value that existed before we reset it and then select the content.
  setTimeout("var d=document.getElementById('"+el.id+"'); d.value=\""+v+"\";d.focus();if(d.value.length>1){d.select();}",100);
}
```

**What does it do?**

- Firstly it adds an `&nbsp;` space to the field so the browser tries
  to find details related to that but doesn't find anything, so that's
  auto-complete fixed
- Secondly, when you click, the HTML is created again, cancelling out the popup and then the value is added back selected.
- Finally, when you delete the string with the Delete button the popup usually ends up appearing again but the keyup check repeats the process if we hit that point.

**What are the issues?**

- Clicking to select a character is a problem but for a sign in page most will forgive the fact it select all the text
- Javascript does trim any inputs of blank spaces but you might want to do it too on the server side to be safe

**Can it be better?**

Yes probably. This is just something I tested and it satisfies my basic need but there might be more tricks to add or a better way to apply all of this.

**Tested browsers**

Tested and working on latest Chrome, Firefox, Edge as of this post date

Answer (score 2):

I must have spent two days on this discussion before resorting to creating my own solution:

First, if it works for the task, ditch the `input` and use a `textarea`. To my knowledge, autofill/autocomplete has no business in a `textarea`, which is a great start in terms of what we're trying to achieve. Now you just have to change some of the default behaviors of that element to make it act like an `input`.

Next, you'll want to keep any long entries on the same line, like an `input`, and you'll want the `textarea` to scroll along the y-axis with the cursor. We also want to get rid of the resize box, since we're doing our best to mimic the behavior of an `input`, which doesn't come with a resize handle. We achieve all of this with some quick CSS:

```css
#your-textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Finally, you'll want to make sure the pesky scrollbar doesn't arrive to wreck the party (for those particularly long entries), so make sure your text-area doesn't show it:

```css
#your-textarea::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Easy peasy. We've had zero autocomplete issues with this solution.

Comment: How do you prevent users hitting "enter"?

Answer (score 2):

After trying all solutions (some have worked partly, disabling autofill but not autocomplete, some did not work at all), I've found the best solution as of 2020 to be adding type="search" and autocomplete="off" to your input element. Like this:

```
<input type="search" /> or <input type="search" autocomplete="off" />
```

Also make sure to have autocomplete="off" on the form element.
This works perfectly and disables both autocomplete and autofill.

Also, if you're using type="email" or any other text type, you'll need to add autocomplete="new-email" and that will disable both perfectly. same goes for type="password". Just add a "new-" prefix to the autocomplete together with the type.
Like this:

```
<input type="email" autocomplete="new-email" />
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password" />
```

Answer (score 2):

> (It works in 2021 for Chrome (v88, 89, 90), Firefox, Brave, and Safari.)
>
> The old answers already written here will work with trial and error, but most of
> them don't link to any official documentation or what Chrome has to say on this
> matter.

The issue mentioned in the question is because of Chrome's autofill feature, and here is Chrome's stance on it in this bug link - *[Issue 468153: autocomplete=off is ignored on non-login INPUT elements, Comment 160](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468153#c164)*

To put it simply, there are two cases -

- ***[CASE 1]***: Your `input` type is something other than `password`. In this case, the solution is simple, and has three steps.
- Add the `name` attribute to `input`
- `name` should not start with a value like email or username. Otherwise Chrome still ends up showing the dropdown. For example, `name="emailToDelete"` shows the dropdown, but `name="to-delete-email"` doesn't. The same applies for the `autocomplete` attribute.
- Add the `autocomplete` attribute, and add a value which is meaningful for you, like `new-field-name`

It will look like this, and you won't see the autofill for this input again for the rest of your life -

```
  <input type="text/number/something-other-than-password" name="x-field-1" autocomplete="new-field-1" />
```

- ***[CASE 2]***: `input` `type` is `password`
- Well, in this case, irrespective of your trials, Chrome will show you the dropdown to manage passwords / use an already existing password. Firefox will also do something similar, and same will be the case with all other major browsers. [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)
- In this case, if you really want to stop the user from seeing the dropdown to manage passwords / see a securely generated password, you will have to play around with JS to switch input type, as mentioned in the other answers of this question.

[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) Detailed MDN documentation on turning off autocompletion - *[How to turn off form autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)*

Comment: Appreciate for your complete explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This will fix this problem

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

Answer (score 2):

you only need autocomplete attribute for this problem
you can [visit this page for more information](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_autocomplete_off.asp)

```
<input type="text" name="foo" autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Internet Explorer 11, there is a security feature in place that can be used to block autocomplete.

It works like this:

Any form input value that is modified in JavaScript *after* the user has already entered it is flagged as ineligible for autocomplete.

This feature is normally used to protect users from malicious websites that want to change your password after you enter it or the like.

However, you could insert a single special character at the beginning of a password string to block autocomplete. This special character could be detected and removed later on down the pipeline.

Comment: This is a horrible solution and would not recommend anyone doing this

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete = 'off' didn't work for me, anyway i set the value attribute of the input field to a space i.e `<input type='text' name='username' value=" ">` that set the default input character to a space, and since the username was blank the password was cleared too.

Answer (score 1):

None of the provided answers worked on all the browsers I tested. Building on already provided answers, this is what I ended up with, (tested) on **Chrome 61**, **Microsoft Edge 40** (EdgeHTML 15), **IE 11**, **Firefox 57**, **Opera 49**, and **Safari 5.1**. It is wacky due to many trials; however, it does work for me.

```
<form autocomplete="off">
    ...
    <input type="password" readonly autocomplete="off" id="Password" name="Password" onblur="this.setAttribute('readonly');" onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" onfocusin="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" onfocusout="this.setAttribute('readonly');" />
    ...
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {           
        $('input#Password').val('');
        $('input#Password').on('focus', function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val().length < 2) {
            $(this).attr('type', 'text');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('type', 'password');
        }
    });
    $('input#Password').on('keyup', function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val().length < 2) {
            $(this).attr('type', 'text');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('type', 'password');
        }
    });
    $('input#Password').on('keydown', function () {
        if (!$(this).val() || $(this).val().length < 2) {
            $(this).attr('type', 'text');
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr('type', 'password');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Just need to add above real input field

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion - MDN
https://medium.com/paul-jaworski/turning-off-autocomplete-in-chrome-ee3ff8ef0908 - medium
                                        tested on EDGE, Chrome(latest v63), Firefox Quantum (57.0.4 64-бит), Firefox(52.2.0)
                                        fake fields are a workaround for chrome/opera autofill getting the wrong fields

```
 const fakeInputStyle = {opacity: 0, float: 'left', border: 'none', height: '0', width: '0'}

 <input type="password" name='fake-password' autoComplete='new-password' tabIndex='-1' style={fakeInputSyle} />

<TextField
  name='userName'
  autoComplete='nope'
  ... 
/>

<TextField
      name='password'
      autoComplete='new-password'
      ... 
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to stop Chrome 66 from autofilling by adding two fake inputs and giving them position absolute:

```
<form style="position: relative">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: -999px; left: -999px;">
    <input name="username" type="text" />
    <input name="password" type="password" />
  </div>
  <input name="username" type="text" />
  <input name="password" type="password" />
```

At first, I tried adding `display:none;` to the inputs but Chrome ignored them and autofilled the visible ones.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me like a charm.

1. Set the autocomplete attribute of the form to off
2. Add a dummy input field and set its attribute also to off.

> ```
> <form autocomplete="off">
>  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" style="display:none">
> </form>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a name in attribute `name` how `email` address to your form and generate an email value. For example:

```
<form id="something-form">
  <input style="display: none" name="email" value="randomgeneratevalue"></input>
  <input type="password">
</form>
```

If you use this method, Google Chrome can't insert an autofill password.

Comment: What do you mean by *"how email address to"* (seems incomprehensible)? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55762165/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

I'v solved putting this code after page load:

```
<script>
var randomicAtomic = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15);
  $('input[type=text]').attr('autocomplete',randomicAtomic);
</script>
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is

`<input autocomplete="on|off">`

But keep in mind the browser support. Currently, autocomplete attribute is supported by

Chrome  17.0 & latest
IE      5.0 & latest
Firefox 4.0 & latest
Safari  5.2 & latest
Opera   9.6 & latest

Answer (score 1):

My solution with jQuery.
It may not be 100% reliable, but it works for me.
The idea is described in code annotations.

```js
    /**
 * Prevent fields autofill for fields.
 * When focusing on a text field with autocomplete (with values: "off", "none", "false") we replace the value with a new and unique one (here it is - "off-forced-[TIMESTAMP]"),
 * the browser does not find this type of autocomplete in the saved values and does not offer options.
 * Then, to prevent the entered text from being saved in the browser for a our new unique autocomplete, we replace it with the one set earlier when the field loses focus or when user press Enter key.
 * @type {{init: *}}
 */
var PreventFieldsAutofill = (function () {
    function init () {
        events.onPageStart();
    }

    var events = {
        onPageStart: function () {
            $(document).on('focus', 'input[autocomplete="off"], input[autocomplete="none"], input[autocomplete="false"]', function () {
                methods.replaceAttrs($(this));
            });
            $(document).on('blur', 'input[data-prev-autocomplete]', function () {
                methods.returnAttrs($(this));
            });
            $(document).on('keydown', 'input[data-prev-autocomplete]', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) {
                    methods.returnAttrs($(this));
                }
            });
            $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
                $(this).find('input[data-prev-autocomplete]').each(function () {
                    methods.returnAttrs($(this));
                });
            });
        }
    };

    var methods = {
        /**
         * Replace value of autocomplete and name attribute for unique and save the original value to new data attributes
         * @param $input
         */
        replaceAttrs: function ($input) {
            var randomString = 'off-forced-' + Date.now();
            $input.attr('data-prev-autocomplete', $input.attr('autocomplete'));
            $input.attr('autocomplete', randomString);
            if ($input.attr('name')) {
                $input.attr('data-prev-name', $input.attr('name'));
                $input.attr('name', randomString);
            }
        },
        /**
         * Restore original autocomplete and name value for prevent saving text in browser for unique value
         * @param $input
         */
        returnAttrs: function ($input) {
            $input.attr('autocomplete', $input.attr('data-prev-autocomplete'));
            $input.removeAttr('data-prev-autocomplete');
            if ($input.attr('data-prev-name')) {
                $input.attr('name', $input.attr('data-prev-name'));
                $input.removeAttr('data-prev-name');
            }
        }
    };

    return {
        init: init
    }
})();
PreventFieldsAutofill.init();
```

```css
.input {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555555;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <p>
    <label for="input-1">Firts name without autocomplete</label><br />
    <input id="input-1" class="input" type="text" name="first-name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Firts name without autocomplete" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="input-2">Firts name with autocomplete</label><br />
    <input id="input-2" class="input" type="text" name="first-name" autocomplete="given-name" placeholder="Firts name with autocomplete" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try to put attribute  autocomplete with value "off" to input type.

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" id="password" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="attendees" id="autocomplete-custom-append">

<script>
  /* AUTOCOMPLETE */

  function init_autocomplete() {

    if (typeof ($.fn.autocomplete) === 'undefined') {
      return;
    }
    // console.log('init_autocomplete');

    var attendees = {
      1: "Shedrack Godson",
      2: "Hellen Thobias Mgeni",
      3: "Gerald Sanga",
      4: "Tabitha Godson",
      5: "Neema Oscar Mracha"
    };

    var countriesArray = $.map(countries, function (value, key) {
      return {
        value: value,
        data: key
      };
    });

    // initialize autocomplete with custom appendTo
    $('#autocomplete-custom-append').autocomplete({
      lookup: countriesArray
    });

  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Leave inputs with text type and hidden.
2. On DOMContentLoaded, call a function that changes the types for password and display the fields, with a delay of 1s.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeInputsType);

function changeInputsType() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(/*selector*/).prop("type", "password").show();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You have to do better than what you just posted to prevent down-voting or flagging for "low quality" answer. Keep in mind you're competing with 82 other answers. Add versioning. End of Review.

Answer (score 1):

I already posted a solution for this here: *[Disable Chrome Autofill creditcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595141/disable-chrome-autofill-creditcard/60664102#60664102)*

The workaround is to set the autocomplete attribute as "cc-csc" that value is the [CSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code) of a credit card and that they are no allowed to store it! (for now...)

```
autocomplete="cc-csc"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simply change the `name` attribute in your `input` element to something *unique* each time and it will never autocomplete again!**

An example might be a time tic added at the end. Your server would only need to parse the first part of the text `name` to retrieve the value back.

```
<input type="password" name="password_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE JAVASCRIPT to fix this!!**

Use HTML to address this problem first, in case browsers are not using scripts, fail to use your version of the script, or have scripts turned off. Always layer scripting LAST on top of HTML.

1. For regular input form fields with "text" type attributes, add the `autocomplete="off"` on the element. This may not work in modern HTML5 browsers due to user browser override settings but it takes care of many older browsers and stops the autocomplete drop-down choices in most. Notice, I also include all the other autocomplete options that might be irritating to users, like `autocapitalize="off"`, `autocorrect="off"`, and `spellcheck="false"`. Many browsers do not support these but they add extra "offs" of features that annoy data entry people. Note that **Chrome for example ignores "off"** if a user's browsers are set with `autofill` enabled. So, realize browser settings can override this attribute.

EXAMPLE:

```
<input type="text" id="myfield" name="myfield" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" placeholder="Enter something here..." title="Enter Something" aria-label="Something" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```

2. For *username* and *password* input type fields, there is some limited browser support for more specific attributes for `autocomplete` that trigger the "off" feature". `autocomplete="username"` on text inputs used for logins will force some browsers to reset and remove the autocomplete feature. `autocomplete="new-password"` will try and do the same for passwords using the "password" type input field. (see below). However, these are propriety to specific browsers and will fail in most. Browsers that do not support these features include Internet Explorer 1-11, many Safari and Opera desktop browsers, and some versions of iPhone and Android default browsers. But they provide additional power to try and force the removal of autocomplete.

EXAMPLE:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20" value="" autocomplete="username" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" placeholder="Enter username here..." title="Enter Username" aria-label="Username" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="20" minlength="8" maxlength="12" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,12}" value="" autocomplete="new-password" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" placeholder="Enter password here..." title="Enter Password: (8-12) characters, must contain one number, one uppercase and lowercase letter" aria-label="Password" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```

**NOW FOR A BETTER SOLUTION!**

Because of the splintered support for HTML5 by standards bodies and browsers, **many of these modern HTML5 attributes fail in many browsers**. So, some kids turn to script to fill in the holes. But that's lazy programming. Hiding or rewriting HTML using **JavaScript makes things worse**, as you now have layers upon layers of script dependencies *PLUS* the HTML patches. Avoid this!

**The best way to permanently disable this feature in forms and fields is to simply create a custom "id"/"name" value** each time on your 'input' elements using a unique value like a date or time concatenated to the field id and name attribute and make sure they match (e.g. "name=password_{date}").

```
<input type="text" id="password_20211013" name="password_20211013" />
```

This *destroys* the silly browser autocomplete choice algorithms sniffing for matched names that trigger past values for these fields. By doing so, the browsers cannot match caches of previous form data with yours. It will force "autocomplete" to be off, or show a blank list, and will not show any previous passwords ever again! On the server side, you can create these custom input "named" fields and still identify and extract the correct field from the response from the user's browser by simply parsing the first part of the id/name. For example "password_" or "username_", etc. When the field's "name" value comes in you simply parse for the first part ("password_{date}") and ignore the rest, then extract your value on the server.

Easy!

Answer (score 1):

I've been fighting this never-ending battle for ages now... And all tricks and hacks eventually stop working, almost as if browser devs are reading this question.

I didn't want to randomize field names, touch the server-side code, use JS-heavy tricks and wanted to keep "hacks" to a minimum. So here's what I came up with:

**TL;DR** use an `input` without a `name` or `id` at all! And track changes in a hidden field

```
<!-- input without the "name" or "id" -->
<input type="text" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email">
```

Works in all major browsers, obviously.

P.S. Known minor issues:

1. you can't reference this field by `id` or `name` anymore. But you can use CSS classes. Or use `$(#email').prev();` in jQuery. Or come up with another solution (there's many).
2. `oninput` and `onchange` events do not fire when the textbox value is changed programmatically. So modify your code accordingly to mirror changes in the hidden field too.

Answer (score 1):

Browser ignores autocomlete on readonly fields. This code makes all writable filds readonly till it's focused.

```js
$(_=>{$('form[autocomplete=off] [name]:not([readonly])').map((i,t)=>$(t).prop('autocomplete',t.type=='password'?'new-password':'nope').prop('readonly',!0).one('focus',e=>$(t).prop('readonly',!1)));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input name="user" id="user" required class="form-control" />
<label class="form-label" for="user">New User</label>
<hr>
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" minlength="8" maxlength="20" />
<label class="form-label" for="pass">New Passwort</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the behavior of `autocomplete` is pretty much unpredictable over different browsers and versions, my approach is a different one. Give all input elements for which you want to disable autofill the `readonly` attribute and only disable it on focus.

```
  document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    readOnlys.forEach(readOnly => {
      if (e.target == readOnly) {
        readOnly.removeAttribute('readonly', '');
        readOnly.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none');
      } else {
        readOnly.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        readOnly.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'auto');
      }
    });
  });
  document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
    if (e.key == 'Tab') {
      readOnlys.forEach(readOnly => {
        if (e.target == readOnly) {
          readOnly.removeAttribute('readonly', '');
          readOnly.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none');
        } else {
          readOnly.setAttribute('readonly', '');
          readOnly.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'auto');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

If you want to make sure that users can still access the fields if they have disabled JS, you can set all `readonly`s initially via JS on page load. You can still use the `autocomplete` attribute as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

**2022 September**

Some browsers such as Google Chrome does not even care the value of `autocomplete` attribute. The best way to stop getting suggestions is changing the name attribute of the input to *something* that changes *time to time*

As of September 2022, browsers will not provide autocomplete for **one time passwords**

So we can use `otp` as the field name.

### <input name="otp">

Comment: I also found this solution independently. But it's better to use `autocomplete="one-time-code"` than to abuse name detection.

Answer (score 1):

For React you can try to put this code either now under a form or above password input or between email and password inputs

```
export const HackRemoveBrowsersAutofill = () => (
  <>
    <input type="email" autoComplete="new-password" style={ { display: 'none' } } />
    <input type="password" autoComplete="new-password" style={ { display: 'none' } } />
  </>
)
```

One of the examples:

```
<input type="email"/>
<HackRemoveBrowsersAutofill/>
<input type="password"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the problem goes on... and it seems no action done by main browsers, or even worst, some actions are done just against any solution. The option:

> autocomplete="new-password"

is not working on some browsers now, as the autocomplete is done with the password generator (that confuses the user as the value is hidden).

For some **empty input fields**, explicitly the case

> type="url"

it is really complicated to avoid incorrect autocompletion, but an **unbreakable space** instead of an empty value do the trick (spaces don't do)...at the cost of some garbagge included in the form (and one of this days the browsers will also autocomplete that)

Very sad.

Answer (score 0):

Just `autocomplete="off" list="autocompleteOff"` in your input and work done for IE/Edge! and for chrome add `autocomplete="new password"`

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting to autocomplete for years. I've tried every single suggestion, and nothing worked for me.
Adding by jQuery 2 attributes worked well:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off').attr('autocorrect', 'off');
    }, 10);
});
```

will result in HTML

```
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" value="" class="input-small hasDatepicker" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Start date" autocorrect="off">
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with Chrome 84.0.4147.105

1. Assign text type to password fields and add a class, e.g. "fakepasswordtype"

```
<input type="text" class="fakepasswordtype" name="password1">
<input type="text" class="fakepasswordtype" name="password2">
```

2. Then use jQuery to change the type back to password the moment when first input is done

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.fakepasswordtype').on('input', function(e){
        $(this).prop('type', 'password');
    });
});
```

This stopped Chrome from its nasty ugly behavior from auto filling.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome keeps trying to force autocomplete. So there are a few things you need to do.

The input field's attributes `id` and `name` need to not be recognizable. So no values such as name, phone, address, etc.

The adjacent label or div also needs to not be recognizable. However, you may wonder, how will the user know? Well there is a fun little trick you can do with `::after` using the `content`. You can set it to a letter.

```html
<label>Ph<span class='o'></span>ne</label>
<input id='phnbr' name='phnbr' type='text'>

<style>
  span.o {
    content: 'o';
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution Just change the label name and fields name other than the more generic name e.g: Name, Contact, Email.
Use "Mail To" instead of "Email".
Browsers ignore autocomplete off for these fields.

Answer (score 0):

Define input's attribute type="text" along with autocomplete="off" works enough to turn off autocomplete for me.

EXCEPT for type="password", I try switching the readonly attribute using JavaScript hooking on onfocus/onfocusout event from others' suggestions works fine BUT while the password field editing begin empty, autocomplete password comes again.

I would suggest switching the type attribute regarding length of password using JavaScript hooking on oninput event in addition to above workaround which worked well..

```
<input id="pwd1" type="text" autocomplete="off" oninput="sw(this)" readonly onfocus="a(this)" onfocusout="b(this)" />
<input id="pwd2" type="text" autocomplete="off" oninput="sw(this)" readonly onfocus="a(this)" onfocusout="b(this)" />
```

and JavaScript..

```
function sw(e) {
    e.setAttribute('type', (e.value.length > 0) ? 'password' : 'text');
}
function a(e) {
    e.removeAttribute('readonly');
}
function b(e) {
    e.setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking arround to find a solution to this but none of them worked proberly on all browsers.

I tried autocomplete off, none, nope, new_input_64, (even some funny texts) because the autoComplete attribute expects a string to be passed, no matter what.

After many searches and attempts I found this solution.

I changed all `input` types to `text` and added a bit of simple CSS code.

Here is the form:

```
<form class="row gy-3">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="fullname" class="form-label">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullname" name="fullname" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="username" class="form-label">User Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pswd" id="password" name="password" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="password" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control pswd" id="password" name="password" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="recaptcha" class="form-label">ReCaptcha</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recaptcha" name="recaptcha" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```

The CSS code to hide password:

```
.pswd {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

**Tested on Chrome, Opera, Edge.**

Answer (score 0):

*NB: I can swear that browser devs are coming back to this page learning new ways to fight our efforts*

### March 2024

Looks like latest Chromium browsers (v.122) do not autosuggest for inputs liek this:

```
autocomplete="otp"
```

Which apparently makes them think, this is a 2FA-password.

I went a little further and discovered that

```
autocomplete="RaNd0m$tring"
```

also works. By `randomString` I mean a new value, every time.

Answer (score -1):

A combo that worked for me in 2023 (checked in Chrome browser):

```
<input
   name='nm-0.239458' // generated with `nm-${ Math.random() }`
   placeholder='Nаme' // where 'а' is cyrilic, it looks exactly like latin 'a'
/>
```

Answer (score -2):

I was having trouble on a form which included input fields for username and email with email being right after username.  Chrome would autofill my current username for the site into the email field and put focus on that field.  This wasn't ideal as it was a form for adding new users to the web application.

It seems that if you have two inputs one after the other where the first one has the term 'user name' or username in it's label or ID and the next one has the word email in it's label or ID chrome will autofill the email field.

What solved the issue for me was to change the ID's of the inputs to not include those words.  I also had to set the text of the labels
to an empty string and use a javascript settimeout function to change the label back to what it should be after 0.01s.

```
setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('id_of_email_input_label').innerHTML = 'Email:'; }, 10);
```

If you are having this problem with any other input field being wrongly autofilled I'd try this method.